# How to find whole string using find()

Tags: python

How to find whole string using `find()` function?

For example my input:

```
word = 'banana'

sentence1 = 'Hello, I very like eat banana'
>True

sentence2 = ' Hello, I very like eat banana1'
>False
```

I want to use `find()` function, because I want get start and end position of this string.

For example:

```
loc = sentence1.find(word)
```

Comment: So what is your problem here?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Something like `H` and `a` or `Hello, I very like eat banana`?

Comment: @Simon Expected output: 23(start position of banana) and end position 28, if my end_loc = loc + len(word) - 1

Comment: @VasilisG. I want to skip sentence2, if word !=  in sentence2

Comment: `find()` checks for substring in a string and since `banana1` as a string contains `banana` as a substring, `find()` will return the position of the substring. If you wish to find the exact word, then you will have to split the sentence and compare each word individually.

Comment: Its probably overkill in this example but regex matches have a `span()` which gives you back a tuple of the position `(20, 25)`

Comment: @SamCollins Thanks! But how to get start and end position of span() to new variable?
For example i want to use start position and end position to further code.

Comment: `a[0]` and `a[1]`, if `span()` is stored in variable `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overkill solution might be to use regex. Your expression could use work boundaries which fixes the problem with the 1 added on.

```
import re
text = 'Hello, I very like eat banana'
start, end = re.search(r'\bbanana\b', text).span()
```

`span` returns a tuple so you can assign it to one variable and it will be like (20, 40) which you can access using [0] etc or into two variables like above.

If you do this often I recommend using `re.compile()` on your regex first.

Comment: Note that this also matches things like `"apple, banana, cherry"`, which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: I assume he wants just the position of the word `banana` which that seems to do